# ActionScript URL Matching Regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, parsing, url, chat

I'm working on a chat system in ActionScript 3 that needs to be able to parse links in messages. I've played with a few regex's of my own, and searched for others. The best one I could find was http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

```
(?xi)
\b
(                       # Capture 1: entire matched URL
  (?:
    https?://               # http or https protocol
    |                       #   or
    www\d{0,3}[.]           # "www.", "www1.", "www2." … "www999."
    |                           #   or
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?:                       # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+                  # Run of non-space, non-()<>
    |                           #   or
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
  )+
  (?:                       # End with:
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
    |                               #   or
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]        # not a space or one of these punct chars
  )
)
```

And it works great in PCRE, JavaScript, and Python.

Because both JavaScript and ActionScript are dialects of ECMA Script, I thought it'd work with ActionScript too. However, it seems to have some issues and I was hoping someone could help with sorting them out.

Regex101: http://regex101.com/r/pP7dV0
WonderFl: http://wonderfl.net/c/oALh

:: **WONDERFL SHOWS THE IMPLEMENTATION.** :)

Comment: For what it is worth, the pattern itself seems to work fine in Flash. See [RegExr](http://regexr.com?37tts) (a Flash-based RegEx tester from Grant Skinner, one of the more prolific Flash devs out there). My guess is it is in the implementation, not the RegEx itself.

Comment: Agree with Josh here. Maybe post your implementation for us.

Comment: @tenub They did. Second link. I'm debugging it now

Comment: Can't figure out why it isn't working, though I am admittedly not giving it my full attention. For the record, you should use `String.match()` instead of `RegEx.exec()` and your match will be Index 0, not 1.